# XSLT list multiple values

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I Have XML similar to this(omitted parts for brevity):

```
  <uformrecord>
      <state>Submitted</state>
      <created>2012-06-19T11:31:54</created>
      <updated>2012-06-19T11:32:13</updated>
      <id>53225sas3c1-d727-42cd-93a6-97cd778e5ee9</id>
      <ip>123.45.3.60</ip>
      <pageid url="/blah.aspx" name="Vacancy Application">1873</pageid>
      <memberkey emaillogin=""></memberkey>
      <fields>

        <ifyouhavetickedyeshowwouldyoudescribeyourdisabilitytickallthatapplytoyou record="532253c1-d727-42cd-93a6-97cd778e5ee9" sortorder="1" pageindex="2" fieldsetindex="0">
          <key>73b9150d-c65c-4ec0-9c8f-8d334b0495bf</key>
          <fieldKey>07a8ade7-ae13-41e6-bc3a-fe8444bcf9b0</fieldKey>
          <caption>If you have ticked 'Yes', how would you describe your disability (Tick all that apply to you.)</caption>
          <datatype>String</datatype>
          <values>
            <value key="c6de1932-9bba-4691-b19e-a44b5bb68c6c">I have a hearing problem</value>
            <value key="dd902bdb-89d7-4f14-ab60-4e69e803f321">I use a wheelchair</value>
            <value key="322c8e15-f722-406c-9d10-1769a2fb306e">I am dyslexic</value>
          </values>
        </ifyouhavetickedyeshowwouldyoudescribeyourdisabilitytickallthatapplytoyou>

      </fields>
    </uformrecord>
```

Im applying xslt and doing something like this:

```
<xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$records//fields/ifyouhavetickedyeshowwouldyoudescribeyourdisabilitytickallthatapplytoyou//value != ''">

     <xsl:value-of select="$records//fields/ifyouhavetickedyeshowwouldyoudescribeyourdisabilitytickallthatapplytoyou//value"/>

        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          NO DISABILITIES MENTIONED
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
```

This just outputs the first value ('I have a hearing problem')

How can i make it list all the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested (replaced the very long node name with "longname")...

```
<xsl:for-each select="$records//fields/longname//value">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:if test="not($records//fields/longname//value)">
  NO DISABILITIES MENTIONED
</xsl:if>
```

**EDIT**

I've updated the above, as I think the `!= ''` is unnecessary

Answer (score 1):

Your code will output all the values if you run it as an XSLT 2.0 stylesheet: XSLT 2.0 changes the behaviour of xsl:value-of so it outputs all the values, not only the first.